# Is there a way to include more than one 'if' conditional for output?

Tags: c

I have this code below (whole code after this section). I am wanting to include more than one casse for this section of the code:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if(numberArray[i] == 1)
            {
                casse = 2;
            }
            if(numberArray[i] == 2)
            {
                casse = 3;
            }
            if(numberArray[i] == 1 || numberArray[i] == 2)
            {
                casse = 4;
            }
        }
```

So far, the above prints '4' when the value '8213' is entered. This is expected since for each round of for loop the 'casse' variable gets updated, by the time it runs the last integer in the array, the value for 'casse' has undergone many replacements and the end result is the last replacement of '4'.

> The objective of the code is to determine which cases (casse) have
> been met. There can be more than one case (casse) being met, but as it
> stands now, it only has room for one case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    
    int odo, value, casse;
    int i;
    
    printf("please enter a value for the odometer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &odo);
    
    value = odo;
    casse = 0;
    
    int length = floor(log10(abs(odo))) + 1;
    
    
    /* count number of digits */
    int c = 0; /* digit position */
    int n = value;

    while (n != 0)
    {
        n /= 10;
        c++;
    }

    int numberArray[c];

    c = 0;
    n = value;

    /* extract each digit */
    while (n != 0)
    {
        numberArray[c] = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        c++;
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", numberArray[i]);
    }
    
    
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(numberArray[i] == 1)
        {
            casse = 2;
        }
        if(numberArray[i] == 2)
        {
            casse = 3;
        }
        if(numberArray[i] == 1 || numberArray[i] == 2)
        {
            casse = 4;
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n%d\n", casse);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
please enter a value for the odometer:
8213
3, 1, 2, 8, 
4
```

Expected output:

```
please enter a value for the odometer:
8213
3, 1, 2, 8,

Not only '4', but also '3', '2'.
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. What is wrong with the output?

Comment: Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result. It also would be helpful to give the overall description of what the code is supposed to do (not individual lines of code but the overall objective).

Comment: it could be that more than one case (casse) is the result of having a number like 8213. Case 2 (casse 2) is if there's at least a number '1' in '8213', while case 3 is if there's at least a number '2' in '8213'. Both of these cases (casse) are met, but the output would only be one value (either case 2 or case 3).

Comment: Then is sounds like you want to print the value of `casse` every time it changes.  So do exactly that.

Comment: dbush: More like I would like to store it and not print. I plan on doing something with it afterwards, if it meets certain specific cases (casse).

Comment: @Jonathan Then you need an array to store multiple values and an associated counter.

Comment: Store multiple values of casse: YES!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a single variable that keeps track of the last case, you want an array which keeps track of all cases.  For a small number of cases, the array can be a fixed size, with the index as case number and the value in the array as the number of times that case was triggered:

```
int cases[5] = {0};
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(numberArray[i] == 1)
        {
            cases[2]++;
        }
        if(numberArray[i] == 2)
        {
            cases[3]++;
        }
        if(numberArray[i] == 1 || numberArray[i] == 2)
        {
            cases[4]++;
        }
    }
```